# Change value of a cell depending on contents of column of another google sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a Google sheet with information on it and I am trying to automate it a bit.  I need a formula which changes a cell value to Yes if there are specific strings in the column of another sheet.  I have tried a couple different things using IF and importrange but it's just not working.

I have created a sample sheet to show what I am trying to do:
[Test Sheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17HkXo7_XzO4Zvqnu6SpLTYbeF1eS_aVL3XePyy_ghUY/edit#gid=0)
[Test Sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM/edit#gid=0)

I would like column C of Sheet 1 to change to Yes if Columns 1 and 2 of both sheets match and Column C of Sheet 2 contains "Reloaded" or "Yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!A2:A")&
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!B2:B"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!C2:C")}, 2, 0), 
 "Yes|Reloaded")=TRUE, "Yes", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF((D2:D="User Task")*(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!B2:B"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!C2:C")}, 2, 0), 
 "Yes|Reloaded")=TRUE), "Yes", )))
```

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your response. I understand what is going on. I actually added another condition. Column E in test sheet 1 should only populate if Column D is a "User Task".  Also the date columns do not need to match up but I can edit that part out on my own.

Comment: Hey player0, I am trying to understand this as I would like to add more conditions to be met.  I understand what all of the formulas do individually but am having a hard time understanding how it all comes together.  I have never seen '*' used inside an IF statement.  Is that just mean both of those statements inside the IF need to be true? Inside the vlookup, the B2:B is the search key.  The range is both columns B and C in Sheet1.  This is where I get lost.  I don't understand the rest starting from the 2, 0

Comment: sure, '*' is equivalent of AND in ARRAYFORMULA because OR and AND are not supported in AF. understand it as 0/1 logic... 1 * 1 = 1 (true multiplied by true is true). meanwhile in VLOOKUP... 2 represents the 2nd column so from B:C search in B and if found return C. and the ending 0 means "exact match" so only if B2:B is exactly found in Sheet1:B:B

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I am having one more issue.  Hate to keep bothering you but I can't figure it out.  On Test Sheet 2, I added another column called 'Type'.  I would like Column E in Test Sheet 1 to say yes if 'Type' = Customer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
={
  "Complete";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        (IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!A2:A") = A2:A)
      * (IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!B2:B") = B2:B)
      * (REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1YMBUYC6JgQke-2YWs_VZx9zqlmOdhV8WYvhTpTVxBYM", "Sheet1!C2:C"), "Reloaded|Yes")),
        "Yes",
        ""
    )
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your response.  I understand what is going on.  I actually added another condition.  Column E in test sheet 1 should only populate if Column D is a "User Task".